# check if nvcc is available in makefile

Tags: cuda, compilation, makefile, nvcc

I have two versions of a function in an application, one implemented in CUDA and the other in standard C. They're in separate files, let's say *cudafunc.h* and *func.h* (the implementations are in *cudafunc.cu* and *func.c*). I'd like to offer two options when compiling the application. If the person has nvcc installed, it'll compile the *cudafunc.h*. Otherwise, it'll compile *func.h*.

Is there anyway to check if a machine has nvcc installed in the makefile and thus adjust the compiler accordingly?

Thanks a bunch,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, included in your Makefile:

```
        NVCC_RESULT := $(shell which nvcc 2> NULL)
        NVCC_TEST := $(notdir $(NVCC_RESULT))
ifeq ($(NVCC_TEST),nvcc)
        CC := nvcc
else
        CC := g++
endif
test:
        @echo $(CC)
```

For GNU make, the recipe line(s) (after `test:`) actually start with tab characters.

With the above preamble, you can use [conditionals](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_7.html) based on the `CC` variable to control the remainder of your Makefile.

You would change the `test:` target to whatever target you want to be built conditionally.

As a test, just run the above with `make`.  You should get output of `nvcc` or `g++` based on whatever was detected.

Comment: Erm... you should definitely _not_ start those first lines with TAB characters.  You should not use TAB characters to indent _any_ of those lines, except you must use a TAB to indent the recipe line (the `@echo ...` line)

Comment: It seems to work fine with GNU make using TAB characters on all the lines I indicated.  However I've modified the answer to reflect only putting a TAB on the recipe line.

Comment: It will work, as long as those are the first lines in the makefile.  But if there's any rule prior to those lines it will fail badly, because all lines that begin with a TAB are assumed to be part of a make rule recipe, unless there's no recipe context available.  In general it's best to not confuse the issue and say that TABs should only ever be used to introduce recipe lines, and never anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a conditional, like

```
ifeq (($shell which nvcc),) # No 'nvcc' found
func.o: func.c func.h
HEADERS += func.h
else
func.o: cudafunc.cu cudafunc.h
        nvcc -o $@ -c $< . . . 
CFLAGS += -DUSE_CUDA_FUNC
HEADERS += cudafunc.h
endif
```

And then in the code that will call this function, it can test `#if USE_CUDA_FUNC` to decide which header to include and which interface to call.

Comment: The use of the `__CUDA_ARCH__` preprocessor symbol could be also useful in this case.