# dynamic include a CUDA file

Tags: c++, c, cuda, makefile, header-files

I have two solvers for an application, one in C and other in CUDA. The Makefile detects if nvcc is available and automatically switches to use the CUDA solver. Otherwise, it should use the C solver.

I wanted to include the header of the CUDA solver only if nvcc is detected, so I did this in the main.cpp file:

```c
#if (NVCC_TEST == nvcc)
    #include "utilCUDA.h"
#endif
```

NVCC_TEST is declared in the Makefile like this:

```
NVCC_RESULT := $(shell which nvcc 2> NULL)
NVCC_TEST := $(notdir $(NVCC_RESULT))
```

The problem is that the main file includes utilCUDA.h even when nvcc is not available in the system. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables defined in the make environment don't automatically show up at the source code level when compiling.  Referring to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599434/check-if-nvcc-is-available-in-makefile), in the section of your Makefile where you set make variables for CUDA vs. non-CUDA usage, do the following:

```
        NVCC_RESULT := $(shell which nvcc 2> NULL)
        NVCC_TEST := $(notdir $(NVCC_RESULT))
ifeq ($(NVCC_TEST),nvcc)
        CC := nvcc
        CCFLAGS := -DUSE_CUDA
else
        CC := g++
        CCFLAGS := -DNO_CUDA
endif
```

Then whereever in your Makefile you are specifying the compile command, add the `$(CCFLAGS)` to the compile command line.  Any source code compiled in that command line will see that define.

Then in your source code, you can do:

```
#ifdef USE_CUDA
#include "utilCUDA.h"
#endif

#ifdef NO_CUDA
// whatever else you want to do.
#endif
```

By the way, if you attempt to compile a `.cpp` file with `nvcc`, you're probably not going to get the results you expect.  If you need to do this, use the `nvcc -x cu` [option](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#file-and-path-specifications) when you specify your compile command.